# Is it possible to mount an overlay over / right after boot?

Tags: linux, embedded, overlayfs

### Background:

I have an embedded system with both flash and SD storage.

Currently I use flash just for booting (uBoot, kernel, initramfs).

Root filesystem (`/`) is on SD (`ext3` on `/dev/mmcblk0p2`).

I (sometimes) experience SD failures when power is suddenly removed (I cannot prevent that, unfortunately).

I would like to divide Root filesystem in two overlays, so that the bulk of the system is 'lower' read/only, stored in flash (possibly *replacing* initramfs) while the application dependent "upper" overlay is on another read/write `ext3/4` partition on SD.

ALL pieces needed to full boot should be on "lower", so that the system can work if "upper" is (temporarily) lost.

`/tmp`, `/var` and other place needing to be read/write are already on `tmpfs`, so system can boot with a read/only `/`.

In case of failure "lower" can try to recover and, as last resort completely `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p3` and reinitialize it.

### Question:

How can I mount a partition `overlay` over `/` ?

I read documentation, but I'm a bit confused as all examples seem to work with directories different from `/`; can I do something like:

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /ovr
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/,upperdir=/ovr,workdir=/ovr overlayfs-root /
```

early after boot (ideally in `/etc/inittab`, as I'm using Busybox `init`)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/109413/how-do-i-use-overlayfs

In a nutshell, you have to mount `/` somewhere else, or bind mount it there, before you mount the overlayfs.